# I've got the persistent live version I was dreaming of, how do I make an ISO file to share it?

Tags: live-usb, iso, dd

Created a live USB of Lubuntu 16.04 and made it work the way I like (installed new programs and customized plenty of configuration files). Now, it is installed in a 4GB pen drive, but it occupies some 2GB. How can I create an ISO file storing only that content. `dd` would dump the entire 4GB storage, but I want it to have the minimal size, so it can be easily downloaded and installed somewhere else. Can `dd` be parametrized to do it? Any specific software for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handily, the Ubuntu community [has a page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) detailing what you need to do.

This page covers the software you need to prepare the squashfs which your newly rolled distro will use, how to go through the process of customisation (yov'e indicated you've already done this, but there are some tips in there on how you could do this other ways), gives you some warnigns and tips and shows you how to create the Live CD at the end of it. Hopefully that covers everything you need.

It looks like you'll be able to skip some sections of that page sicne you've already got an enviroment set up. It may pay to read those sections anyway since they may contain useful warnings and tips.

Comment: Great. And now I can see why I didn't end up here, as I've searching for live USB (not CD :). For those that want to go straightforward to the ISO creation procedure, click [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Producing_the_CD_image). BTW, thanks for elaborating on it.

Comment: That's the Ubuntu community wiki, which used to be editable by everyone. Saying "Canonical have a page" makes it more "official" than it actually is.

Comment: May be it's a stupid question: what's supposed to be the 'edit' directory used in this page? It's referred plenty of times, but I get errors of the kind: 'Cannot stat source directory "edit" because No such file or directory'.